# asp.net ashx image simple example not compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I am trying to get this simple example working from http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx.

When I add the '<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>' first line the compiler highlights every line and gives two errors as per screenshot.

I have tried visual studio build actions of 'Content' and 'Compile' but no difference.

[image: Screenshot]

I've got to be missing something simple here!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove  '<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>' form .ashx.cs file. This is for .ashx file.

To view the content of .ashx file, right click on .ashx file & click on View Markup as shown the screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks that has resolved my issue. Also after I posted I managed to import a text file I created with the contents shown above and with .ashx and this worked.